# Mi 9T Pro System Destroyed

Tags: adb, fastboot, xiaomi, system-error, android-10

So, I wanted to install Lineage OS on my MI 9T Pro and I've made a mistake (I know why.)

I've use TWRP to access to recovery, I'll erase all folder (system/data/vendors/cache) and I'm trying to install lineage, but my OS folder was in a folder into my zip and an error was occured.

In the panic, I've rebooted the phone, and a message "The system was DESTROYED" appears on my screen, but I've access to Fastboot. I've trying some Fastboot erase (Data/system (no access)/Boot/cache) AND !

I've lock by mistake my phone with a Fastboot oem lock, but I succeeded to unlock it with Mi software.

I'm trying an Fastboot devices, all are okay I've a device connected, but, if I try an adb devices i don't have devices connected.

I have push a miui folder (~90mb) in boot, and now it restarted only in Fastboot mod, no other message, no other possibility. and I've tried a reboot in recovery, nothing, same in "android OS mod", only Fastboot reboot.

I've trying to flash with MiFlash a global rom but error 0xfffffff has occurred.

Today, I'm totally stuck and I don't know what to do, I don't have backup for a potential restoration.

Impossible to have access to debug mod to my Mi 9T Pro because I don't have access to OS and developer mod.

Apparently the battery is charging (always ON) with USB.

If u have some tricks for me, it's with pleasure!

Comment: download stock ROM and flash *boot.img recovery.img system.img vendor.img* from fastboot *'fastboot flash <partition> <file>*' and format userdata + cache *'fastboot format:ext4 <partition>'* (*<file>* means full path to image on PC)

Comment: @alecxs I've some stock rom on PC but I've only boot.img in zip folder.
do u have a link for download all img ? I can't find this files...

Comment: https://xiaomifirmwareupdater.com/archive/miui/raphael check for "fastboot" in download description

Comment: @alecxs thanks u it's all good now !